# OS installed fonts are not available in Storyboard dropdown

Tags: xcode, macos

I am using xcode 10.1, recently I have updated mac os from 10.13.6 to 10.14.2 and after that the installed fonts are not available from storyboard; When I change the type to attributed text, installed fonts is showing in font box but in plain text only the system fonts are showing;
Is any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the fonts on your system first by double clicking it, or opening your FontBook app (double clicking should open the FontBook app)
2. Add font(s) to application bundle
3. Restart Xcode

:) hope this helps

Comment: I delete my font, install it again and the main action to fix my problem is Restart xcode after adding font

Comment: @Fa.Shapouri I am glad that your problem was solved. Wishing you the best on your project.